# asp.net update textbox via JS based on other textbox value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datetime, textbox

I have two textboxes on my asp.net page.
One is for today's date and one is for the expiry date which is one year from now.

So if the first textbox contains 23/04/2013

I want the second textbox to be automatically populated with 23/04/2014

How can I update the expiry date's date to be exactly one year from now (without postback)
I suspect some JS is needed right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses jQuery to read the date, parse the parts and add one to the year.  It doesn't, however check the validity of the date entered, so entering letters into the first textbox would produce a date of "NaN/NaN/NaN".  You could combine this with jQuery UI's [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to make sure the input is a valid date.  In that case you would use the `change` event instead of `keyup`.

**Html:**

```
<input id="today" type="text" />
<input id="future" type="text" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#today').keyup(function () {
        var today = new Date($(this).val());
        if (today != NaN) {
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth();
            var y = today.getFullYear();
            $('#future').val(dd + '/' + mm + '/' + (parseInt(y)+1));
        }
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6vs5y/

Answer (score 1):

```
function update(sourceTBId, targetTBId){
    document.getElementById(targetTBId).value = document.getElementById(sourceTBId);
}


<input type='button' onclick="update('<%=textbox1.ClientID%>', '<%=textbox2.ClientID%>')"/>
```

where textbox1 is the source and 2 is the target.

Oh sorry you said automatically...

In the code behind do this

textbox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "update('"+textbox1.ClientID+"', '"+textbox2.ClientID+"')");

As for the dates, if you're certain it's going to be dd/mm/yyyy then this should do it (there may be more elegant/better ways - and this will fail if the format is wrong - also this is all air code so please check it)

```
function update(sourceTBId, targetTBId){
    var dateString = document.getElementById(sourceTBId);
    var dateParts = dateString.split("/");
    var dd = dateParts[0];
    var mm = dateParts[1];
    var yy = 1 + parseInt(dateParts[2]);

    document.getElementById(targetTBId).value = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yy;
}
```

would be far better to use any date parse and format methods but I'm not familiar enough to say this quickly whether they even exist in JS.

Comment: Thanks but I am aware of the button trick. I need it to do the same but without any buttons/clicking. So when the user leaves textbox1, textbox2 should auto update. I want JS to calculate the new date also. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure just change onkeyup in my revised answer to onblur

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but how to handle Date() in JS so that I can add 1 year to the date from textbox1 and then display that in textbox2?

Comment: Have added, as I say using Date would be good but from my brief look at the API there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a date format for parse().